# Help me make sense of the Starcraft 2 ending

Tags: starcraft-2

Upon seeing that opening vid, I actually thought all marines were convicts sentenced to death and put in the front line as their death penalty. But it seems to me that only Tychus has this deal with Mengsk. In that case, it is safe to assume that it was Mengsk who set Tychus to join Raynor's Raiders.

But in the ending scene, Tychus' orders seem to be actually to kill Kerrigan, not Raynor (I thought he was supposed to kill or bring Raynor to Mengsk). But for that to happen, was Mengsk expecting that Raynor would actually go and try to save Kerrigan? That it was just his convenience that Kerrigan was converted back?

Or was it a huge conspiracy of sorts where Mengsk told his son to get Raynor to help him become his father's successor (much more believable than Mengsk dealing with Raynor himself). I mean it was Valerian who researched and fixed the artifact right? So was Arcturus counting on that for Tychus to have a shot at Kerrigan?

Comment: The fact that Kerrigan is no longer the Queen of Blades, seriously hurts the Zerg. So sometimes your enemies enemy is your friend, even if you have a beef with him too (Raynor in this case)

Comment: This will involve a lot of speculation until the next two expansions come out and explain everything.

Comment: @Jonn or follow in footsteps of things like 'Lost' and pose more questions ;)

Comment: What if Tychus was Valerian's spy?

Answer (score 3):

Most marines are "resocialized" former criminals, convicts, etc. with reapers and firebats being particularly egregious villains pre-rehabilitation.

The key difference with Tychus, is that Mengsk knew he had a history with Raynor. Perhaps resocialization engenders massive personality and memory change -- quite simply, if Mengsk wanted to use Tychus to get a pawn into Raynor's forces, resocialization might kill the connection.

So Mengsk needed some other way to ensue Tychus' loyalty. Hence the prison-suit.

What I *can't* tell you is why Mengsk wanted Kerrigan dead more so than Raynor, especially after *Media Blitz*. Perhaps the implication is that Tychus was always a spy to Mengsk, and when Mengsk saw an opportunity to hurt Raynor, commanded Tychus to kill her, even if that hadn't been his original intent in setting Tychus free.

On an unrelated note -- without Kerrigan, I'm a little bit confused as to who is going to be the central character for the Zerg expansion campaign. :/

*No information above can be considered canon, and is just the random speculation of a fan.

Comment: The Zerg campaign will be part prequel to wings of liberty

Comment: Source? 8morechar.

Comment: A friend of mine theorized that may Kerrigan can still control the Zerg, even though she is human again.

Comment: I agree with the supposition that Mengsk sent Tychus at first with general orders to keep tabs on Raynor, radio back with information, and generally be ready to screw with his plans. When Tychus reports that Raynor is on a path to go rescue Kerrigan, Mengsk orders Tychus to wait around until he has a shot at her, as allowing her to return as Raynor's ally would potentially be far more dangerous than Raynor on his own.

Comment: If you read the unit personalities/bios in the Armory, Firebats and Reapers are nearly polar opposites, and their psychotic tendencies are due to the chemical leaks in their respective suits.

Comment: At one point in the campaign Raynor explains why he thinks Mengsk won't go after him, simply because he's more dangerous as a martyr than as a failed revolutionary.

Comment: @VxJasonxV that would be Firebats and Marauders are polar opposites.

Comment: Errr. Right :).

Answer (score 0):

Mengsk was directly responsible for the destruction of Tarsonis and indirectly for the creation of queen of blades. Kerrigan is a living reminder of what he done.

Mengsk experimented with zerg-protos hybrids, I wouldn't be very surprised to see some sort of grand plan of the Xel'Naga (Mengsk being controlled by the Xel'Naga or something like that). We didn't really see what actually happened with Terrans in the future vision.

Comment: I thought they said all the Terrans were dead already

Comment: @BlueRaja Well it said that the Terrans were consumed (doesn't necessary mean dead).

Answer (score 0):

Raynor loved part of kerrigan, and blamed himself for failing to save her on tarsonis. In a way, he blames himself for the monster that she became. When raynor was given a real chance to save Kerrigan (by purging the zerg side of her), he was able to overcome his hatred and in doing so regain his spirit.

Also, the reason kerrigan became evil was because the infestation process removed her sense of morality and ethics, leaving only the pain and anger at being betrayed and exploited. The darkness was there, but was unleashed by the infestation.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the story makes the most sense when you don't think about it too hard. The immediate question that comes to mind is whether Valerian and Mengsk where together in this or not:

Was it all a very devious plan to kill Kerrigan. Perhaps the idea behind it all is that you cannot kill Kerrigan without making her human again, but then there is no real need for Tychus. He can just order Valerian to kill her once she obtains human form.

Perhaps Tychus was supposed to remain an agent for Mengsk on Raynor, and Mengsk just seized the chance when he had it, without being coordinated with Valerian, but that seemingly contradicts what Tychus says himself.

It is all definitely baffling.

Answer (score -1):

My personal theories:

Mengsk is "The Dark Voice", or under its direct control. He knows Kerrigan is prophesized to stand in the way of his goals, so he keeps trying to kill her. (Apparently Tassadar also found out about her and Overmind being central to stopping him.)

Also, having a spy/saboteur that can alter your enemy's decisions is far more useful than creating a martyr and losing invaluable intelligence and influence.

Suddenly everything fits...

Comment: Why the downvotes. Please explain why you disagree?

Comment: I'm guessing because Mengsk doesn't make sense as the "Dark Voice" given his utter ignorance of anything Xel'Naga or protoss? But I can't speak for those who actually voted.

Comment: Where is it proven that he's not just playing dumb? He's been using psi emitters to make zerg do his bidding ever since the beginning.